# adding vertical scroll to my own custom manager in blackberry jde 6

Tags: blackberry, jde

I want to add vertical scroll feature to my own custom manager, but i am not getting it,
as of now i am passing style bits VERTICAL_SCROLL|VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR to the constructor
of my own custom manager

Comment: Could you post your code so we can help?

Comment: Hey why you could not post your code.
We can't give any solution without your code.
Understand.......................................................

Answer (score 2):

1. Please post your code
2. Call super on constructor if you are extending any other manager class
3. An easy fix is to nest your custom manager inside a `VerticalFieldManager` with scroll.

Comment: sorry due to some reason i was out of that project, and also not available on the stackoverflow...